# Check internet connectivity without using ping

Tags: networking

How can you check if internet is connected without using ping. Can we use telnet instead. What else can be used to determine if network is available or not.

Answer (score 1):

Question is vague so the answer will be vague but I assume you mean "how can we know that we are able to leave the LAN and traffic is going out to the Internet and reaching it's target".

You can use telnet, SSH, DNS, WHOIS, cURL, traceroute etc.

In a way you need simply to see the connectivity with an outside device.

Comment: Yes sorry for that. The issue I'm facing is quite irrelevant. I just want to know can we check it without connecting to a particular server like without doing telnet to google.com. How can know that internet is connected.

Comment: You will need to discuss to a device that is not on your LAN to be sure you have connectivity outside.
Now of course you can check your routing table etc and if you have access to professional grade routers, see the BGP routes you are receiving but like I said in the end protocol are involved and discussions are going between devices.